# PL SQL : Create oracle record dynamically

Tags: oracle, plsql

I dont know if it is possible but I would like to do this in PL/SQL

Let's say I have a parameter in my procedure, a number : numberColumns.

Inside the procedure I would like to create a record :

```
TYPE arrayColumn IS RECORD (
   column1 VARCHAR2(200),
   column2 VARCHAR2(200)...
   ... as much à numberColumns value
   ....
);
```

ty

Comment: Can you give an example of how you would use this? (Or why you would even want to?) This seems to be an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/332810) that would possibly be better solved using an entirely different solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved easily with with OBJECT type in Oracle. But this kind of architecture is not at all suggested. Hope this below solution helps.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE test_obj_form(
    a NUMBER )
AS
  lv_sql VARCHAR2(32676);
BEGIN
  SELECT '('
    ||listagg(str,',') WITHIN GROUP (
  ORDER BY lvl)
    ||')'
  INTO lv_sql
  FROM
    (SELECT 1 dum,
      'column'
      ||LEVEL
      ||' '
      ||'varchar2(200)' str,
      level lvl
    FROM dual
      CONNECT BY LEVEL < A
    ORDER BY LEVEL
    )
  GROUP BY dum;
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE name_rec IS OBJECT '||lv_sql;
  dbms_output.put_line(lv_sql);
END;
/
```

Comment: If the procedure is used multiple times with different number of columns then this will redefine the object (in the SQL scope) and lead to concurrency issues where somewhere else in the code is trying to use it with `X` columns and then it gets redefined with `Y` columns.

Comment: Yes exactly thats why i said this is a very bad idea to use this kind of architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a record, you could use a collection:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE stringlist IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000);
/
```

Then do:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE your_procedure(
  number_columns IN  INTEGER,
  values         OUT stringlist
)
IS
BEGIN
  values := stringlist();
  IF number_columns < 1 THEN
    RETURN;
  END IF;
  values.EXTEND( number_columns );
  FOR i IN 1 .. number_columns LOOP
    values(i) := DBMS_RANDOM.STRING( 'X', 100 ); -- Assign some value
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Otherwise, if you really want a record, then you will have to result to dynamic SQL.

Comment: to @MT0 , If I understood the question right, author just needs an array of strings like  CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE stringlist IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(200);, am I right or not ?

Comment: @Seyran if you are just talking about the length of the strings in the array then, yes, they could use 200 or 4000 or whatever precision they feel is appropriate. The second half of my example is how to populate and return it from the procedure (which they will probably also need).

Comment: Sorry @MT0 , my mistake, it seemed to me you advised to create a record  with collection member.